# Tuple is a dictionary key in counter - how do I make it a string?

Tags: python, counter

I am new to Python. I used collections.Counter to count the most frequent bigrams in a  text:

```
import sys, codecs
import nltk, collections
from nltk.util import ngrams

InputFile = codecs.open("testin.txt", 'r', 'utf-8')
text=InputFile.read().lower()
tokens = text.split() 
bi_tokens = ngrams(tokens, 2)
bi_freq = collections.Counter(bi_tokens)
```

If I use:

```
for row in bi_freq.most_common(100):
    print (row)
```

The result appears as:

```
(('star', 'wars'), 29)
(('blu', 'ray'), 21)
```

If I use:

```
for row in bi_freq.most_common(1000):
    print (row[0], "\t", row[1])
```

The result appears a bit cleaner as:

```
('star', 'wars')     29
('blu', 'ray')   21
```

I would like to get to:

```
star wars    29
blu ray      21
```

which I would import into a spreadsheet in two columns with tab as a separator.

So my question is: how do I access each tuple value, when the tuple is a key in a dictionary, so that I can concatenate them into a string?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `' '.join(row[0])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join()` to create a delimited string from a sequence.

```
for bigram, c in b_freq.most_common(1000):
    print(" ".join(bigram), c)
```